# Adjoint of an operator-valued linear operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-product

I have come across a linear bounded operator $B:K\to \mathcal{L}(U,Z)$ where $K$, $U$, and $Z$ are separable Hilbert spaces. I need a reference (any source) to find out about:

- The adjoint of such an operator, something that enables me to write, roughly speaking,
  $$\langle z,(Bk)u\rangle_Z= \langle (B^*u)z,k\rangle_K$$
- A way to expand an element $B(k)\in \mathcal{L}(U,Z)$ based on eigen functions of $U$ and $Z$ (if separable).

Comment: This question deserves a more specific title but I can't come up with one at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $u \in U$, the map that takes $(z,k)$ to $\langle z,(Bk)u\rangle_Z$ is a bounded sesquilinear form on $Z\times K$. (Bounded because $|\langle z,(Bk)u\rangle| \leq \|z\|\|(Bk)u\| \leq \|B\|\|u\|\|z\|\|k\|$.) Therefore there exists a bounded linear operator $B^*u$ from $Z$ to $K$ satisfying $\langle (B^*u)z,k\rangle_K = \langle z,(Bk)u\rangle_Z$ for all $(z,k) \in Z\times K$. That's a standard consequence of the Riesz representation theorem. I can't really make sense of what is meant by "eigenfunction of $U$" in the second question.

Comment: I meant a basis for U, and Z as well.

Comment: Well, if $(e_i)$ is an orthonormal basis for $U$ and $(f_j)$ is an orthonormal basis for $Z$ then the matrix entries for $Bk$ would be the values $\langle (Bk)e_i, f_j\rangle$.

Comment: Is it  possible to find out what $B^*$ yields acting on particular elements $z=(z_i)$, $k=(k_i)$, $u=(u_i)$ of $\ell ^2$?